# Google translation API single request limit

Tags: python, google-translate

I'm getting:

```
Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)
```

Using the new Google Cloud [Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2015-q1-cloud-northam-us-bigdata-bkws-freetrial-en&gclid=CN3k0JqCv9MCFZI1aQodfW8A2Q), via Python client. I need to cut my text limit, but not able to find the limit. My request contained 15185 characters.

Looks like my error is not related to Quota limits:

https://cloud.google.com/translate/limits

```
google.cloud.exceptions.GoogleCloudError: 413 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>413.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client issued a request that was too large.
 <script>
  (function() { var c=function(a,d,b){a=a+"=deleted"+("; path="+d);null!=b&&(a+="; domain="+b);document.cookie=a+"; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"};var g=function(a){var d=e,b=location.hostname;c(d,a,null);c(d,a,b);for(var f=0;;){f=b.indexOf(".",f+1);if(0>f)break;c(d,a,b.substring(f+1))}};var h;if(4E3<unescape(encodeURI(document.cookie)).length){for(var k=document.cookie.split(";"),l=[],m=0;m<k.length;m++){var n=k[m].match(/^\s*([^=]+)/);n&&l.push(n[1])}for(var p=0;p<l.length;p++){var e=l[p];g("/");for(var q=location.pathname,r=0;;){r=q.indexOf("/",r+1);if(0>r)break;var t=q.substring(0,r);g(t);g(t+"/")}"/"!=q.charAt(q.length-1)&&(g(q),g(q+"/"))}h=!0}else h=!1;
h&&setTimeout(function(){if(history.replaceState){var a=location.href;history.replaceState(null,"","/");location.replace(a)}},1E3); })();
```

Comment: Did you notice there is a limit of 100,000 Characters per 100 seconds per user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same situation here although I found the following in the docs:

https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas

https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq

In the second link there is a specific question about chars per request and it says it shouldn't be more than 5000